# How to define a trigger keyword in OpenSearchDescription xml file?

Tags: triggers, subdomain, keyword, opensearch, omnibox

I am trying to get an open search definition to work on subdomains.

I have added the correct line in the `<head>` of the html.

Example:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Example" href="http://www.example.org/opensearch.xml" />
```

In opensearch.xml:

```
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
<ShortName>Example</ShortName>
<LongName>Example Search</LongName>
<Description>Example Description</Description>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
<Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">http://www.example.org/favicon.ico</Image>
<Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://www.example.org/search/{searchTerms}" />
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

The search is correctly added to the omnibox settings in Google Chrome, when I visit http://www.example.org. The trigger keyword becomes "example.org".

However, when I visit http://subdomain.example.org, which has the same line in the `<head>`, the search is added with trigger keyword "subdomain.example.org" instead of "example.org".

Is there a way around this?

I have not found any information on how to set the trigger keyword in the documentation at http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1 .

Comment: I'd like to know as well.  Maybe Chrome's OpenSearch processing has hostname hardcoded as the default keyword.  Would be nice if it exposed a way to define this string ourselves.

Comment: It would be awesome if Chrome would just use the ShortName property.  I cannot find anywhere in Chrome source code that Chrome looks at a property of the OSD to set the keyword.